# measuring one-way packet delay: any synchronization needed?

Tags: synchronization, delay, packet

I have one machine sending packets at a constant rate (one every x milliseconds) to another one. I need to measure the one-way delay for each packet.  One idea could be for the first machine to record the instant when it sent the first packet, and once all transfers have been done, let the second machine know about it, so it can compute the delay for each packet starting from that value.

Do I need any specific synchronization here? I don't know whether this will yield a considerable error on my measurements.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-Pairs_Protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Send 10k one-way packets to the destination.
2. Send a "finished" message to the destination
3. Destination replies with "all received"
4. Once the reply arrives you know how long it took

You'll have a tiny systematic error in the measurement because of the confirmation message needed, but that will be small. With real-world latencies it totally works. The calculated latency is: `(a*10000+a+b)/(10000+1+1)`. For `a` ~ `b` this term becomes just `a`.

Alternatively, tightly synchronize the clocks (difficult) and send timestamps.

Comment: That's one idea, yeah. But I need to be able to scale the time interval between each packet so that I can saturate the link, leave it uncongested, etc.

Comment: If you just want to saturate the link, why don't you increase load while measuring packet loss? You can find the optimal point that way.

Comment: One-way delay is not half of the round-trip time... You cannot estimate one-way delay without synchronization. Even if you send millions of messages from A to B during 10 days, you cannot know in which direction messages travel faster or slower. If A->B is slow and all your messages arrive at B the 10th day, B will just send back "all received" but A doesn't know when this reply has been sent. A could think that all messages arrived at B the first day, and that the reply needed 9 days to arrive back at A. You simply cannot calculate one-way direction without external synchronization.

Comment: @Timmos true, but with practical latencies it totally works. The calculated latency is: (a*10000+a+b)/(10000+1+1). For a ~ b this term becomes just a. I removed the broken alternative (2) from my answer. Not sure what I was thinking at the moment.

Comment: Even then your formula cannot hold, because you are sending 10000 packets from A->B but you start sending a message when you're done with sending the previous message. Being done with sending a message doesn't mean it has arrived at B. So actually, what you're calculating is how fast you can send messages, but not how long it takes for messages to travel from A->B.

Comment: I come to think you're right. We are basically measuring throughput, not latency. If throughput is very high and latency is one day the formula will output 1d/10000 which is clearly wrong. I'll think about this a little more. Maybe this technique is still useful in real-world networks. What do you think?